# cudaGetDevice function what does it do not so clear?

Tags: cuda

I am working on a cluster where I have 4 GPU's connected to a compute node. All the GPU's are same basically k20 no difference there. I want to know on which GPU my binary is running? cudaGetDevice gives me device id 0 always where as my binary is actually running on device id 2(checked using nvidia-smi)

Using this device Id I want to measure the power consumed using NVML library.

```
cudaGetDevice :Returns in *device the current device for the calling host thread.
```

Any other method to get this info ?

Comment: It may be that you are working in a cluster where specific GPUs are assigned to you when you run a job.  In this case, the job scheduler software may be using `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to [restrict the GPUs your code can run on](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars).  This will affect the ordering and logical indexing of GPUs available to your code (i.e. what is reported by `cudaGetDevice` or what is available using `cudaSetDevice`), but has no effect on `nvidia-smi`.  This is likely the reason for the difference.

Comment: Do you need any additional assistance or have you been able to achieve your goal with the below answer already?

Answer (score 2):

From [nvidia smi doc](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/cuda/files/CUDADownloads/NVML_cuda5/nvidia-smi.4.304.pdf):

> **-i, --id=ID**
>
> Display data for a single specified GPU or Unit. The specified id may
>   be the GPU/Unit's 0−based index in the natural enumeration returned by
>   the driver, the GPU's board serial number, the GPU's UUID, or the
>   Display data for a single specified GPU or Unit. The specified id may
>   be the GPU/Unit's 0−based index in the natural enumeration returned by
>   the driver, the GPU's board serial number, the GPU's UUID, or the
>   GPU's PCI bus ID (as domain:bus:device.function in hex). **It is
>   recommended that users desiring consistency use either UUID or PCI bus
>   ID, since device enumeration ordering is not guaranteed to be
>   consistent between reboots and board serial number might be shared
>   between multiple GPUs on the same board**.

So what I would do would be to call [cudaGetDeviceProperties](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g5aa4f47938af8276f08074d09b7d520c.html#g5aa4f47938af8276f08074d09b7d520c) and as advised would investigate returned properties such as pciBusID. Then, based on what device is found on desired PCI bus I would call [cudaSetDevice](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g418c299b069c4803bfb7cab4943da383.html) with appropriate parameter.

Comment: Since I am running on a cluster I cannot call cudaSetDevice().

Comment: I am afraid I dont understand why.

Answer (score 0):

`cudaSetDevice` and `cudaGetdevice` always work on **logical** visible devices from `0` to `num_visible_devices`. For example, if you `setenv CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES 3,6`, and execute code `cudaSetDevice(1)`, your code will actually work on **physical** device `6`, not `1`.